# Are my two female guppys pregnant

Tags: guppies

[image]
In my ten gallon I have two females and one male both females look like this one and if anyone could tell me about how long till birth that would be great

Answer (score 2):

The [gestation period](http://small-pets.lovetoknow.com/gestation-period-guppies) for a Guppy fish is between 21-30 days, with the average often being 22-26 days.  Warmer fish tanks appear to help pregnant guppies from exceeding their due date:

> Gestation may last from 21-30 days, although 22-26 days is average for most guppy pregnancies. A warmer tank - between 72-79 degrees Fahrenheit - is best for gestation and will keep the female from being pregnant too long.

I would also say by the looks of it, that they do look pregnant, though it's a little hard to tell through the blurriness.

Here is a picture for reference:

[image: Guppy fish]