# Dalmation molly pregnant?

Tags: fish, breeding

My dalmation molly is pretty dark, so I can't see a gravid spot, she is very swollen and belly looks big, is there any other way to see if she is pregnant?

[image]

Comment: because guppies and mollies are the same species, you could look for this question: [Are my two female guppies pregnant?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/are-my-two-female-guppys-pregnant/16525?r=SearchResults#16525)

Comment: @Allerleirauh Guppies and mollies aren't the same species, but you are close to the truth because they are of the same genus, and genus is only one level higher than specimen in taxonomy system. I guess you intended to mean that, or referred to the fact that they are both live-bearing ^.^ and yes, she looks gravid, even though she is opaque and gravid spot is invisible, I could tell by her shape.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how close she is?

Comment: Oh you're welcome ^.^ It's hard for me to tell, she looks like the pregnancy is advanced, but please note that as far as I know Dalmatian mollies have gestation period which is the longest of all mollies, it could take up to 70 days, so while it definitely looks for me like it's rather close, it could take a while until one day you'll hopefully find a pleasant and cute surprise in your aquarium <°)>><

Comment: You can read about mollies here https://www.fishkeepingworld.com/molly-fish/ or do a search on top of this page,you can look for Q&As about platy and guppy they are in the same family as mollies are.

Comment: @lila yes I choose the wrong term -.- thank you :)

Comment: It seems like she gave birth but I haven’t seen any babies, her belly is a lot smaller

Comment: @MariaSabas Oh that's sad, how does your aquarium setup look like? Is it mainly plain open space with clear sight on the whole volume? If it's the case, the babies could have been all eaten; most fish are cannibals and even mothers would eat their own babies.